# how to multiply multiple df columns

Tags: r, purrr

I have a df with a number of columns.
I want to multiply each of the column using a fixed constant.
I am looking for the best possible strategy to achieve this using `purrr` (I am still trying to get my head around `lamp` etc etc)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data.frame(
               date = ymd(c("2019-02-01", "2019-02-02", "2019-02-03", "2019-02-04",
                        "2019-02-05")),
                  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  y = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                  z = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
       )
```

The constants to multiply each of the column is as follows:

```
c(10, 20, 30)
```

This is the output I expect:

```
data.frame(
        date = ymd(c("2019-02-01", "2019-02-02", "2019-02-03", "2019-02-04",
                 "2019-02-05")),
           x = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
           y = c(40, 60, 80, 100, 120),
           z = c(90, 120, 150, 180, 210)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `map2` from `purrr` (part of the `tidyverse`) to achieve this.

```
df1[2:4] <- map2(df1[2:4], c(10, 20, 30), ~.x * .y)
df1        
#         date  x   y   z
# 1 2019-02-01 10  40  90
# 2 2019-02-02 20  60 120
# 3 2019-02-03 30  80 150
# 4 2019-02-04 40 100 180
# 5 2019-02-05 50 120 210
```

The base R equivalent is `mapply`.

```
df1[2:4] <- mapply(FUN = function(x, y) x * y, df1[2:4], c(10, 20, 30), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```